# How can i to add many div inside UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to add some div via Code behind to html page

I have problem about that from 10 to div just to add the first div inside "swiperwrapper" div

Code behind:

```
    string Img = "";
    string Name = "";
    string Price = "";
    SqlDataReader Val = DAL.Product.Get_Product_Default(GParentCod);
    while (Val.Read())
    {
        Img = "Shopty-UI/" + (Val["Picture"]).ToString();
        Name = (Val["Name"]).ToString();
        Price = (Val["Price"]).ToString();
        //Create Div swiperslide
        HtmlGenericControl swiperslide = new HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
        swiperslide.Attributes.Add("class", "swiper-slide");
        swiperwrapper.Controls.Add(swiperslide);
        .
        .
        .
        //Create span price
        HtmlGenericControl price = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        price.Attributes.Add("class", "price");
        price.InnerHtml = Price + " تومان";
        regularprice.Controls.Add(price);
    }
```

Html Code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
           <div id="swiperwrapper" runat="server" class="swiper-wrapper">
           </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="IMGBTN01" EventName="click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When i dont use of updatepane evrything is good work

Comment: Since "everything works" without the UpdatePanel, the problem must be that the display is not updated in the panel. Is your code-behind sample executed in response to a click on `IMGBTN01`? Can you make a test with a Label inside the UpdatePanel, and modify its text in code-behind? Also, it would be help us to see the markup for the button.